# Does using a "Try Catch" when adding new code to delivered code create a safety margin?

Tags: javascript, performance, integration-testing, robustness

This is more of a conceptual question but specifically, I am programming (currently) into a javascript file that contains a massive amount of delivered code (IE the vendor supports their delivered code and not our customizations).

Because it is essential that the delivered code **always** execute, does my method of always encapsulating my customized code with a `try{} catch(e){}` ensure that even if my custom code fails, that the delivered code will execute?

I encapsulate every bit of custom code. Even if I am to use a delivered variable, I assign it to a custom var and even that one line assignment is encapsulated in a `try{} catch(e){}`.

Does this method work? Is this method overkill and/or how can it be improved?

Here is what I currently do:

```
//delivered code
var global1 = true;
var global2 = true;

//my custom code 
try{
  var custom_global3 = true;
} catch(e){
  console.error(e);
}

//more delivered code
if(global1)
  doSomethingAwesome(global2);

//my custom code 
try{
  makeItLessAwesome(custom_global3);
} catch(e){
  console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed an example of what you're doing, rather than this abstract description. It's hard to figure out how your code and the original code fit together.

Comment: Except your custom code introduce some syntax errors where even `try catch` cannot help any more…

Answer (score 2):

This will catch run-time errors, but not syntax errors at parse time (or ["early errors" in ECMAScript terms](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-16)). For example,

```
try {
    var foo = 1;
    }             // oops..
} catch(e) {
    // never used
}
```

Here, there's a bracket mismatch, so the parser can't figure our where the `try` ends and the `catch` begins. It's obviously not possible that the `try`-`catch` could catch that parse error, because the error is being *caused by* a malformed `try`-`catch` before any code actually runs.

Another example of a parse-time early error is an invalid left-hand assignment, like `4 = 5`:

```
try { 4=5; } catch(e) { /* never used */ }
```

A possibly better approach (depending on how your code is structured) is to place your custom code in separate files or `<script>` tags. A syntax error will stop an entire script file (or `<script>` section) from running, but if your other code is in a totally different file/`<script>`, that's not a problem.

Finally, a truly awful solution would be to place all of your custom code inside of strings in `eval` statements, and place those `eval` statements into `try`-`catch` blocks:

```
try {
    eval("4=5;")
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e); // we caught the error... but at what cost??
}
```

`eval` is really bad, in terms of performance, because you've stopped to parse and run an entirely new script, whereas normal code outside of an `eval` is parsed on the first pass of the parser with everything else. Avoid this solution if is it at all possible. (`eval` is also very bad in terms of security, but that's only an issue if you dynamically build your code strings, like `var v = "alert('reallybad')"; eval("var foo = " + v);`. *Don't dynamically build your code strings!*)

Comment: Thanks, is my try catch method seen anywhere else in industry? I would love to put my goodies in another `<script>` tag altogether but many times it is impractical. My IDE generally helps with most "early errors".